# Does wasb protocol support on on-premises, when using distcp?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-blob-storage, distcp

I want to move my workloads from on-premises to azure blob. Can I use distcp to move the workloads to azure? Since it is blob, I will use wasb in my destination parameter. Will wasb work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** DistCp (distributed copy) is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying. It uses MapReduce to effect its distribution, error handling and recovery, and reporting. It expands a list of files and directories into input to map tasks, each of which will copy a partition of the files specified in the source list.

If you have an HDInsight cluster with access to Data Lake Store, you can use Hadoop ecosystem tools like Distcp to copy data to and from an HDInsight cluster storage (WASB) into a Data Lake Store account. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-wasb-distcp) provides instructions on how use the Distcp tool.

If you want to transfer data to and from Azure Blob, you may refer below articles:

[Transfer data with the AzCopy on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy).

[Transfer data with the Azcopy on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `fs.azure` properties to the core-site.xml, then you can distcp between any Hadoop compatible filesystem  to Azure

[See the documentation for an example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html#Protecting_the_Azure_Credentials_for_WASB_with_Credential_Providers)